# Android RadioGroup behaves differently when RadioButtons added programmatically

Tags: android, radio-group

I am creating a custom RadioGroup defined as follows.

*MyRadioGroup.cpp*

```
public class MyRadioGroup
        extends RadioGroup
{
...
    public MyRadioGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        init(attrs);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_radio_group, this);
    }

    public String getSelection()
    {
        View radioButton = findViewById(getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        return radioButton.getTag().toString();
    }
}
```

*my_radio_group.xml* has a few buttons defined as follows...

```
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbOne"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/rb_selection_background"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:tag="One"
        android:text="Radio Button 1"
        android:textColor="@color/rptText"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
...
</merge>
```

*rb_selection_background.xml* drawable

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/simple_border"
        android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

With this setup I get my desired result of no circle button and the selected button shows a simple border around the text.

I then made a change to dynamically generate my radio buttons from a string array resource. Like this...

```
private void init(AttributeSet attrs)
{

    Drawable selectionBg = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),
                                              R.drawable.rb_selection_background,
                                                   null);

    String[] rbStrings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rb_strings);
    for(int i = 0; i < rbStrings.length; ++i)
    {
        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(mContext);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.weight = 1;
        rb.setText(rbStrings[i]);
        rb.setTag(rbStrings[i]);
        rb.setTextSize(18);
        rb.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        rb.setButtonDrawable(0);
        rb.setBackground(selectionBg);
        addView(rb, lp);
    }
}
```

Now no matter which radio button I click on the simple border is always displayed on the last radio button. The state of the radio group is correct because when I call getSelection() it does return the tag of the radio button that was selected.

Back to my question, Why is the behavior different? Is there a way I can get my desired behavior when adding the radio buttons programmatically? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

changing

```
rb.setBackground(selectionBg);
```

to

```
rb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rb_selection_background);
```

worked.

I don't have an explanation why, I need to look further into each method.